# Best selling product cant be added to cart

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I just took over a Magento site and noticed that the best selling products cant be added to cart, if I click on any item it adds a different item. The site: http://radiantdirect.co.za/

This is somehow new and confusing to me, I am aware that I am expected to try and solve this issue before asking for help, however I just hit a block this time around and dont know where to start. Help will be appreciated

**The home page custom layout XML**

```
<remove name="breadcrumbs" />
<reference name="content">

<block type="slider/slider" name="slider" template="catalog/slider/slider.phtml" />

<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">


<action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>



<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>

<action method="setProductsCount"><count>4</count></action> 

</block>
```

**price.phtml code**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>

<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying product price in different places (products grid, product view page etc)
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
 */
?>
<?php
    $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
    $_weeeHelper = $this->helper('weee');
    $_taxHelper  = $this->helper('tax');
    /* @var $_coreHelper Mage_Core_Helper_Data */
    /* @var $_weeeHelper Mage_Weee_Helper_Data */
    /* @var $_taxHelper Mage_Tax_Helper_Data */

    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_storeId = $_product->getStoreId();
    $_id = $_product->getId();
    $_weeeSeparator = '';
    $_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
    $_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
    $_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);
?>

<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmount = $_weeeHelper->getAmountForDisplay($_product); ?>
    <?php if ($_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(Mage_Weee_Model_Tax::DISPLAY_INCL_DESCR, Mage_Weee_Model_Tax::DISPLAY_EXCL_DESCR_INCL, 4))): ?>
        <?php $_weeeTaxAmount = $_weeeHelper->getAmount($_product); ?>
        <?php $_weeeTaxAttributes = $_weeeHelper->getProductWeeeAttributesForDisplay($_product); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_weeeTaxAmount; ?>
    <?php if ($_weeeHelper->isTaxable() && !$_taxHelper->priceIncludesTax($_storeId)): ?>
        <?php $_attributes = $_weeeHelper->getProductWeeeAttributesForRenderer($_product, null, null, null, true); ?>
        <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_weeeHelper->getAmountInclTaxes($_attributes); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="price-box">
    <?php $_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice()) ?>
    <?php $_regularPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), $_simplePricesTax) ?>
    <?php $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()) ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
    <?php $_weeeDisplayType = $_weeeHelper->getPriceDisplayType(); ?>
    <?php if ($_finalPrice >= $_price): ?>
        <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
            <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)): // including ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                    <span class="weee">(
                        <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                            <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        )</span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                    <span class="weee">(
                        <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                            <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        )</span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, false) ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)): // including ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, true) ?>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, true) ?>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, true) ?>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
                <span class="regular-price"><?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price,true,true) ?></span><br />
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, true) ?>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>
        <?php $_originalWeeeTaxAmount = $_weeeHelper->getOriginalAmount($_product); ?>

        <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)): // including ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Was:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                <p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Now:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                </p>
            <?php else: ?>
            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Now:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // incl. + weee ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Was:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Now:') ?></span>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <span class="weee">(
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                    <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                )</span>
            <span class="price-including-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </span>
            </p>
        <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Was:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Now:') ?></span>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <span class="weee">(
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                    <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                )</span>
            <span class="price-including-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </span>
            </p>
        <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Was:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Now:') ?></span>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, true, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </p>
        <?php else: // excl. ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Was:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_regularPrice, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                <p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Now:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="price-including-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, true, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>
            <?php else: ?>
            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Now:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>

    <?php // MLu Show discounted percentage and price ?>
    <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
    <?php 
    $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price) * 100); 
    $_saveAmount = number_format(($_price - $_finalPrice), 2);  
    ?>
        <p class="yousave">
            <span class="price-label label">You Save: </span>
            <span class="price">
                <strong class="save-amount">R<?php echo $_saveAmount; ?></strong> (<?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%)
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php // Mlu Show discounted percentage and price ?>


    <?php if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPriceValue && $_minimalPriceValue < $_product->getFinalPrice()): ?>

        <?php $_minimalPriceDisplayValue = $_minimalPrice; ?>
        <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(0, 1, 4))): ?>
            <?php $_minimalPriceDisplayValue = $_minimalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
        <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
        <?php endif?>
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as:') ?></span>
            <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_minimalPriceDisplayValue, true, false) ?>
            </span>
        <?php if ($this->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        </a>
        <?php else:?>
        </span>
        <?php endif?>
    <?php endif; /* if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPrice && $_minimalPrice < $_finalPrice): */ ?>
    </div>

<?php else: /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>
    <?php
    $_exclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue);
    $_inclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, true);
    ?>
    <?php if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPriceValue): ?>
        <div class="price-box">
            <p class="minimal-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Starting at:') ?></span>
                <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                    <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_exclTax, true, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="price-including-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_inclTax, true, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php
                    $_showPrice = $_inclTax;
                    if (!$_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax()) {
                        $_showPrice = $_exclTax;
                    }
                    ?>
                <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_showPrice, true, false) ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; /* if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPrice): */ ?>
<?php endif; /* if (!$_product->isGrouped()): */ ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the code you've pasted in your question is related to the issue.

Take a look at the two URLs that are there for each product, the one linked from the Details button, and the one linked from the Add To Cart button. They both reference different product IDs. I don't know why without seeing the code responsible for that part of the page though.

Comment: Could you share with us your code for the best sellers section as I think that is the issue. All products add to cart buttons have the same product id and it appears to be the id of the first item.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your website and i am not sure but may the issue is due to the fact that you have passed static value to the add to cart button you created.

Your code is :

```
<a href="http://radiantdirect.co.za/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5yYWRpYW50ZGlyZWN0LmNvLnphLw,,/product/271/?SID=ack4ik0gp4fmd51dv65mac4lc0">Add to Cart</a>
```

> If you check in all the links same id i.e 271 is being passed

Use this code for adding code via query string:

```
<?php

$formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>

<form action="/checkout/cart/add/product/<?php echo $productid; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />

    <input type="text" name="qty"> QTY

    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

clear your cache and try again.
if the above doesn't work make sure you comment

```
'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
```

in `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but still getting the same error. :(